# How to check an array in a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

So I need to check an array in my query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ".$select." LIKE '%".$search."%'  AND  ID NOT IN '" .$Lastvar."'";
```

`$Lastvar` is my array. I have no idea where to go from here an any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's my full query:

```
$Lastvar = array();
mysql_select_db('submisions', $dbconn);
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ".$select." LIKE '%".$search."%' AND ID NOT IN (" . join(", ", $Lastvar) . ")";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'No results were found';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'an array to make in my query'? If you just want to retrieve the result as array, use mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

Comment: Sorry that was bad English, fixed now.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. Don't worry about the English, can happy to all of use :) I've nothing to add to the answers below, should do the trick for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

If the ID is of integer type:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ".$select." LIKE '%".$search."%'  
AND ID NOT IN (" . join(", ", $Lastvar) . ")";
```

Comment: Im not getting any results any more. Even if what I search is exactly word for word what I need. Any chance you could check and make sure I set up my array right? I posted the full query in OP.

Comment: Well you do set your array up, but you don't add any data to it! Thus your query gets an error because of `AND ID NOT IN ()`

Comment: Well that's actually encased in a for loop. At the end of the for loop I put the ID I got in the array and then the next time I go through it wont grab that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ".$select." LIKE '%".$search."%'  AND  ID NOT IN ('" .join("', '", $Lastvar).")";
```